# bash script not working with multiple arguments

Tags: git, bash, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make an alias to git commit

```
function gcam() {
  git commit -a -m $@ ;
  git status
}
```

when I invoke the command with `gcam 'something'` it works correctly, but if the message has a space in the middle, like `gcam 'new commit'` appears the message `Paths with -a does not make sense`

I was looking [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501325/bash-passing-script-arguments/6501343#6501343), but it doesn't work for me, because i'm using `$@` and not `$1`.Why using `$@`? Is just if i need to pass an additional argument to git commit.

Any idea to make it works this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mat is half right: you should double-quote the `$@`, then quote the message as well. `"$@"` expands to the list of arguments, each as a separate word (i.e. it's as though each argument was individually quoted):

```
function gcam() {
  git commit -a -m "$@"
  git status
}

gcam "commit message" -v
```

This does the equivalent of:

```
git commit -a -m "commit message" -v
git status
```